# Lightweight JSON call to get all POSTS from WORDPRESS Blog

Tags: json, wordpress

I want to fetch all blog posts from a Wordpress Blog simply by JSON. 
I can't use PHP for that. Is there any Mechanism for that??

Like Twitter you get JS/ jQuery solution to fetch all posts.Is there any SAME type Mechanism for WORDPRESS Blog , to get all POSTS???

Please help guys....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using a plugin developed for such a purpose. This one is listed on the WordPress.org website, and it seems like it may help you.

[JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)

In the future it's always best to check the WordPress.org hosted plugins first.